Why Gaussian Process Regression (GPR) is non-parametric?
Given that Gaussian Process (GP) regression relies on a kernel with specific hyperparameters that control the relationships and smoothness between points, can GP regression truly be considered a non-parametric technique? I have the following points.

A GP's behavior is largely determined by the kernel's parametric structure, which restricts the functional form to be consistent with certain assumptions (e.g., smoothness, periodicity). This makes it a deterministic process governed by hyperparameters, not an inherently flexible, parameter-free model.

Like any parametric technique (e.g., AR models), as the amount of data grows, GPs allow for more precise estimates of hyperparameters that better fit the data. This improvement with data could be considered similar to reducing sub-optimality in parameter estimation rather than reflecting an open, parameter-free structure. Furthermore, the ability to draw multiple functions from the posterior distribution (as in parametric models with sampling or bootstrap approaches) does not imply a non-parametric model.

Though each GP realization represents a potential function, they all adhere to the underlying rule established by the kernel, which effectively governs the ways samples can fit the observed data. Consequently, labeling GPs as non-parametric merely because the function form is not entirely predictable may be inaccurate, as the kernel parameterizes and constrains GP flexibility.


In summary, should GP regression not be considered a parametric method due to the kernel's role as a definitive, parameterized structure that guides model behavior? In my opinion, it is indeed a parametric kernel estimator which when used with the Bayesian framework, produces posterior predictions.

See my answer to Is a spline interpolation considered to be a nonparametric model?

I seriously do not understand why I received a downvote. I know different versions of the questions exist, but they are not sufficient for my curiosity. All other posts had similar accepted answers.

@Alexis Thank you for the link to your answer. I am still not convinced why the word "non-parametric" used in this case. Check my comments to the other answers.

+1 To be clear: My comment was not intended as an answer to your question, but as a comment, because I felt the way I framed "nonparametric" there is useful for sharpening discussion about what is or is not parametric. That's all! :)

@Alexis Yes, I completely agree and I appreciate your comment. It helped me articulate as well. The second part of my previous comment is also not really directed to your comment, but to my curiosity itself. Thanks again :)

The points you raised apply to K Nearest Neighbors Regression too.
Let me start by rephrasing what you wrote in terms of K-nearest neighbors regression:
"""
Given that K nearest neighbor (KNN) regression relies on a distance metric with specific hyperparameters [Number of neighbors $K$, Parameter $p$ and dimension wieghts $w_p$ in $\sum_{d=1}^D w_d (|x_{1,d}-x_{2,d}|^p)^{\frac{1}{p}}$] that control the dissimilarities between points, can KNN regression truly be considered a non-parametric technique? I have the following points.

A KNN regressor's behavior is largely determined by the distance's parametric structure, which restricts the functional form to be consistent with certain assumptions (e.g., smoothness, periodicity). This makes it a deterministic process governed by hyperparameters, not an inherently flexible, parameter-free model.

Like any parametric technique (e.g., DFT or AR models), as the amount of data grows, KNNs allow for more precise estimates of hyperparameters that better fit the data. This improvement with data could be considered similar to reducing sub-optimality in parameter estimation rather than reflecting an open, parameter-free structure.


In summary, should KNN regression not be considered a parametric method due to the distance metric/$K$'s role as a definitive, parameterized structure that guides model behavior? In my opinion, it is indeed a parametric estimator.
"""
[Note: I have excluded Point 3 and other text about the fact that a GP is a probabilistic model, which is not relevant.]
So if GPs are parametric, so is KNN regression. Are they indeed both parametric?

How to tell the difference.
In my view, none of what you have mentioned has to do with parametric vs nonparametric. It might be confusing that "nonparametric" methods still have parameters, but they all do.
So how do we tell the difference? I like to use the following demarcation. A method is nonparametric if, after estimating the parameters, we still need the data to make predictions. Otherwise, if having the parameters means we can throw away the data and still make predictions, it is parametric.
Some examples. If I throw away the data, can I still make predictions at point $\mathbf{x}$?

Linear regression: yes, I just calculate $\beta^\top\mathbf{x}$. It must be parametric!
Neural network: yes, I just push $\mathbf{x}$ through my network. It must be parametric!
K nearest neighbors: no; just knowing $K$ and the distance metric is not enough to make any predictions: I need to know the average at the $K$ closest points to $\mathbf{x}$ under my metric. It must be nonparametric.
Gaussian processes: knowing a kernel function's parameters are not enough to make any predictions: I need to know the correlation between all training points and $\mathbf{x}$ as well as the intra-training correlations. Hence it is nonparametric.


Intriguing. Thank you for the answer. This definition goes well with what we observe. However, I still believe it is inappropriate to call estimation techniques parametric or non-parametric. I have a problem with the semantics now. The techniques where the data is needed to make a prediction along with the parameters (can be parameters of the kernel), should be called something else but not non-parametric. The data is required, but the underlying process is defined by its frequency content (kernel). I don't know if other people find the semantics a bit absurd, but I definitely do.

All models are parametric, sure. However, all these approaches/ techniques (GP and KNN too) are also parametric , otherwise there would not be any need to estimate these parameters. Can one fit the data of a GP without estimating the kernel? These kernel define the spectral content, which is physical, not just tuning parameters.

I'm accepting this answer as it is consistent with the literature.

@CfourPiO Regarding: "However, I still believe it is inappropriate to call estimation techniques parametric or non-parametric. " Keep in mind that there never was a committee assembled to determine the best names for statistical concepts: as we were discovering these ideas, names were proposed and some happened to stick, all for purely sociological reasons. Surely there are better ways to name all kinds of ideas. But in order to communicate effectively with the rest of the statistical community, we must nevertheless use the existing terminology in order to be understood.

+1 Nice! I like the way you mark the distinction.

@JohnMadden Thanks a lot for the comment. Coming from a different background other than statistics, I sometimes expect everything to be the way I understand them. However, I should realize this is research and it evolves over time. Thanks for all the help.

Generally speaking, with the way people use the term nonparametric to decribe a model, if you had more data points, there would be more parameters, generally without an upper limit. It doesn't mean "has no parameters" nor is it required to be infinite-parametric with a finite sample size.
To take a different example, consider say spline models. Even though with some given sample you could give a list of parameters and their estimates (that is, after all, how you calculate the smooth fit), it is still nonparametric in this sense of the word.
Similarly nonparametric distributional models for continuous data can be based on things like the ecdf itself or on a histogram or on a KDE. In particular note that with the KDE, even though for a given kernel family (say Gaussian), the kernel itself is "parametric" in the sense that it has a single parameter, the density estimate itself is not fixed-parametric.
In each such case, the number of parameters that describes the function is not fixed and will generally grow with sample size (not always linearly).

+1. In a way, I consider GPs as semi-parametric. The choice of kernel has a massive influence as well as the hyperparameters associated with it (e.g. the length scale of a Gaussian RBF kernel).

Thank you for the answer. I have seen this explanation everywhere. Coming from a background where I deal with random processes (although I am not an expert at all), this explanation does not fit well. Why is it that if an estimation technique produces infinite realizations (infinite functions), it is considered non-parametric and why the hyper-parameters are only tuning parameters? For a random process with a continuous expected frequency response, the kernel decides the evolution. One can draw many realisatizations, but the underlying rule is defined by the kernel whose parameters are fixed.

Calling a method "non-parametric" simply because it lacks explicit parameters is misleading. Each realization still has an associated probability, guided by a kernel function. Poorly estimated kernel parameters can lead to aliasing and frequency broadening. As data points or sample rates increase, the variance and bias in kernel parameter estimation decrease, showing that the process remains fundamentally parametric.
